# Is there a TweenMax equivalent based on opengl/opencv

Tags: opengl, animation, gsap

I'm still relatively new to OpenGL/OpenCV, so I'm still unfamiliar with the multitudes of libraries available for use, particularly for animation. Where I'm from (the Flash world), we have access to several 3rd-party tweening engines that make life very easy for us when we want to programmatically move things around the stage without relying on the (vastly inferior) built-in Adobe tween APIs. One of the most popular is Greensock's TweenMax.

Comment: Is this about OpenGL or OpenCV?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of "move things around the stage" is higher level than OpenGL. In fact, the concept of *things* is higher than OpenGL. All OpenGL renders are triangles (and lines and points). It transforms vertices and renders them as triangles, with some mechanism for filling in the middle part (like mapping a texture). OpenGL has no idea of the persistence of anything; it doesn't know about objects. All it does is draw something where you tell it to.

So if you want something to move, you have to draw it in a different place next frame. If you want to "tween" something, both the tweening and the thing you're tweening has to be implemented by you.